# How to skip if href is none?

Tags: python, scrapy

I parse a page has 20 href to next page. Like this:
[image]

But one of them doesn't has the `href`
[image]

It will cause my code fail.

```
    i = 1000
    j = 0
    dataLen = len(response.xpath('//div[@class="rank_list table rankstyle1"]//div[@class="tr"]'))
    photoNodes = response.xpath('//div[@class="rank_list table rankstyle1"]//div[@class="tr"]')
    for photoNode in photoNodes:
        contentHref = photoNode.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
        yield Request(contentHref, callback=self.parse_page, priority = i, dont_filter=True)
        i -= 1
        j += 1  
    # start parse next page
    def parse_page(self, response):       
        global countLen, dataLen
        enName = response.xpath('//*[@class="movie_intro_info_r"]/h3/text()').extract_first()
        cnName = response.xpath('//*[@class="movie_intro_info_r"]/h1/text()'
        ...
```

I try to add `if not (photoNode is None):` or `if not photoNode ==""` still not working.

```
i = 1000
j = 0
dataLen = len(response.xpath('//div[@class="rank_list table rankstyle1"]//div[@class="tr"]'))
photoNodes = response.xpath('//div[@class="rank_list table rankstyle1"]//div[@class="tr"]')
for photoNode in photoNodes:
    if not (photoNode is None):
        contentHref = photoNode.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
        # photoHref = photoNode.xpath('.//a/img/@src').extract_first()
        yield Request(contentHref, callback=self.parse_page, priority = i, dont_filter=True)
        i -= 1
        j += 1  
    else:
        pass
twRanking['movie'] = movieArray
```

I have no idea how to skip it if it may not has a `href`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems, that you need to check if `contentHref` is not empty, not `photoNode`. `photoNode` anyway will contain information, so it will not be empty. Try something like this:

```
for photoNode in photoNodes:
    contentHref = photoNode.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
    if contentHref:
        # photoHref = photoNode.xpath('.//a/img/@src').extract_first()
        yield Request(contentHref, callback=self.parse_page, priority = i, dont_filter=True)
        i -= 1
        j += 1  
    else:
        pass
```